# Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed. - Symfony - Docker - Yarn

Tags: docker, symfony, yarn-v2

I'm trying to install yarn in my symfony project, but did not succeed yet.

I installed nodejs and all needed requirements on windows. When I type `node -v` or `yarn -v` inside a windows `cmd`, it displays versions for the respective tools as expected.

But in my symfony project inside the container, it seems like the `node` and `yarn` commands can't be found.

Here is a screentshot of my Directory

[image: Directory layout]

When I type `yarn -v` or `yarn install` it gives the following error:

> Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.

I don't know how to fix this error. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use a docker image that has yarn installed. Or install yarn in the image you are using. It's not really much more to it then that.

Comment: Bit off-topic but are you installing yarn because you want yarn or because you think Symfony needs it?  I ask because the webpack bundle is now being installed as part of the default configuration but it is not really needed.  You can just remove it and then the need for yarn as far as Symfony goes, goes away

Comment: @super could you give me an example how to add it to my docker?

Answer (score 0):

***Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.***

Currently working on **Windows 8.1** and first had this issue recently when working with **Gatsby** and also with **Rails**, this issue persisted even though everything was up to date, what worked for both instances was running the ***CMD Line*** in the project directory as **Administrator**, then running **yarn commands**.

Seems to only work in the **CMD Line**, this was just a hunch and it worked.

Sure there is a reference but couldn't find it in the ***Documentation*** to prove the above, if anyone in future comes across the Docs, kindly link it to this post.